# hover effect two class in same time and same way like

Tags: html, css

I am using a class to display an image and I want to add a hover effect in two ways. The first is if I hover on the image the transition effect shows a caption and overlay image.

HTML code:

```
<div class="xoverlay x-simple"> <img class="x-img-main" src="img/best-img.jpg" />
      <div class="xoverlay-box">
        <div class="xoverlay-data"> <span class="x-circle x-white"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> </span> <span class="x-circle x-white"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> </span> <span class="x-circle x-white"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> </span> <span>
          <h2 class="hashTag">#hashTag</h2>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
            the readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
          <a class="x-more"  href="#">More</a></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and my CSS Code :

```
.xoverlay {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    -ms-perspective: 300px;
    -o-perspective: 300px;
}
.x-simple {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

.x-img-main {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
}

.x-img-main:hover{
    width:110%;
    height:auto;
}

.x-simple:hover .xoverlay-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(27,27,27,.7);
}
```

This code as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w9sLpcb/).

Comment: could you share a fiddle or pen and maybe even a scribble that illustrates the aspected behavior... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your current code is that the moment you hover on `x-simple` element, `xoverlay-box` appears in front of img and the hover on img element don't trigger.

You don't have to apply hover on two elements to achieve effects on two elements. You can apply hover on parent element and use that for child elements. In CSS Just replace the

```
.x-img-main:hover{
```

with

```
.x-simple:hover .x-img-main{
```

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w9sLpcb/3/)